# How to get specific echoed value from php function in jquery post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have two files named sample_api.php and test.js.

sample_api.php has following snippet,

```
echo "starting of file";
echo "Executing function";
function valueReturn(){
   $result = array('0'=>array('0'=>'id1',1=>'name1'),'1'=>array('0'=>'id2','1'=>'name2'));
   echo json_encode($result);
}
echo "end";
```

test.js:

```
$.post( api, params, function (data) {
        var result = data;
        alert(result);
```

The `result` has all strings:

**starting of file**

**Executing function**

**{[['id1','name1'],['id2','name2']])**

**end**

How can I get only `json_encode($result);` not all the echoed strings like `echo "starting of file";` in test.js?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can also write these lines as comments like **//starting of file;
//Executing function;**

Comment: then remove other echo statements as there is not meaning to send it to js if they are not useful at all :)

Comment: Pass everything as array and then pick from the necessary index

Comment: I should not comment or remove those lines since these lines are used by others..